# Post start and stop time into mysql(sequelize) using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, node.js

I am building one project management application, i want to track user work start and stop time.

So i have two buttons in UI, **START AND STOP** if User click **START** button, this below function will get current time

```
$scope.start =function(){
     $scope.begin = moment(new Date());
}
```

If user click **STOP** button, this below function will get current time

```
$scope.stop =function(){
    $scope.end = moment(new Date());
}
```

so i want to get two datas $scope.begin and $scope.end in this type of object :

```
{

    time:[

        { begin: 3:59:1 Dec/18/2017 ; end:5:59:1 Dec/18/2017 },
        //if user click again start and stop i want another object dynamically
        { begin: 5:59:1 Dec/18/2017 ; end:6:59:1 Dec/18/2017 }
        { begin: 5:59:1 Dec/18/2017 ; end:6:59:1 Dec/18/2017 }
        { begin: 5:59:1 Dec/18/2017 ; end:6:59:1 Dec/18/2017 }
        //dynamically want add this objects by user operations

    ]

}
```

How to do this i am using angularjs and nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward because you already done it!

```js
//create your time data object
//or maybe get it from your server
$scope.timeData = {
  time:[]
}


$scope.start =function(){
     $scope.begin = moment(new Date());
}

$scope.stop =function(){
    $scope.end = moment(new Date());
    $scope.timeData.time.push({
      begin: $scope.begin,
      end: $scope.end
    })
    
    //and maybe post your timeData to server in order to save them.
}
```